# How to I solve a ValueError: the truth value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.7

I have a data file from which columns of data are selected using pandas. I then use the data from these column to plot it on a scatter graph using matplotlib but i get an error which says: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have searched this problem already on StackOverflow but they don't relate to data plotting

```
# Getting data from column that user selects
variable1 = location_data.iloc[0:-1, columnPosition1]
variable2 = location_data.iloc[0:-1, columnPosition2]

# Converting data from variable1 and 2 to float and storing in list called x & y
for xValue in variable1:
    x.append(float(xValue))

for yValue in variable2:
    y.append(float(yValue))


# x and y are lists which hold data from excel file
# Error begins here
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o')
plt.xlabel(variable1, fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel(variable2, fontsize = 15)
plt.title('A graph of ' + variable1 + ' and ' + variable2)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Computer Science\NEA\Code\Coursework.py", line 115, in <module>
    plot_data(variable1, variable2)
  File "F:\Computer Science\NEA\Code\Coursework.py", line 96, in plot_data
    plt.xlabel(variable1, fontsize = 15)
  File "C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3065, in xlabel
    xlabel, fontdict=fontdict, labelpad=labelpad, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 265, in set_xlabel
    return self.xaxis.set_label_text(xlabel, fontdict, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1564, in set_label_text
    self.label.set_text(label)
  File "C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1191, in set_text
    if s != self._text:
  File "C:\Users\Naima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: This is a common error. Could you copy and paste into your question the actual error message and also some or all of your dataframe?

Comment: Rahim, How to make a [mcve] is a good read that will help get you the answer you need.

Comment: Are you sure the error actually happens at that part of the code?

Comment: @run-out I have made the edits you suggested. Do you require any further code or information?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message with the traceback including at least the line of *your* code where the error originates.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have pasted in the error message and commented where the error begins. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your data *series* as the label *string*:

```
plt.xlabel(variable1, fontsize = 15)
```

Since `plt.xlabel` and `plt.ylabel` do not check the type of the label, they chokes when trying to treat your series as a string.

Set an explicit string as the label instead:

```
plt.xlabel("The X Axis", fontsize = 15)
```